# How to lay out objects in an evenly spaced grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layout

I'd like 36 circles of equal size to be spaced out in a 3x12 (wide) grid. I would like to control the spacing between columns, and between rows, so that I can figure out what is aesthetically optimal by trial and error.

If possible, the space between columns 4&5, 8&9 should be a bit larger, so as to suggest visual grouping of columns into groups of 4. This is not essential, since I can easily do it manually, but would be nice to know.

**I would like to do this all efficiently.** Obviously I can precalculate the X/Y coordinates and tediously enter them for each circle. But who has time for that?

Here's an example of what I want:
[image]

Comment: I don't have any idea what your question is. You seem to know how to place objects evenly, so what are you trying to figure out?

Comment: @Ryan I want to know if there is a tool in Illustrator to automatically space out objects on a grid, which would not be very tedious for a large number of objects (eg. 3600 circles instead of 36). I likewise don't have any idea what your question is.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to say you're looking for a way to automate this in a way that is scalable if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Are these circles already drawn on the board? If not have you tried out the "Transform Effect" option on a single circle? `Effect>Distort&Transform>Transform`? 
Nesting the appearance effects would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw one circle Xpx, copy it horizontally (Object > Move > Copy) fourteen times by Ypx, then select the row of circles and copy them vertically by the same Ypx. Then simply select/delete the fifth and 10th columns.

Comment: It even understands algebraic expressions like `X+Y px`! Perfect. Not quite what I was looking for, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the align tool
Window > Align
there is a tool in here to create equal spacing of a specified width or to create equal spacing between two objects

[image]